# How do I activate a virtual environment in Powershell 2?

Tags: python, powershell

I want to activate this virtual environment:

(G:/virt_env/virt1)

I'm just following a virtualenv tutorial, I have created a virtual environment(look above), the next step Is activating It, but that tutorial was written for Unix, So how do I activate this virtual environment using Powershell 2? This is assuming basic knowledge of Powershell

Edit: Question answered

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? It seems that powershell also supports the ["dot source"](http://superuser.com/questions/71446/equivalent-of-bashs-source-command-in-powershell) command, that should be enough to activate your virtualenv.

Comment: This is what the tutorial provides "source virt_env/virt1/bin/activate"

Comment: Replace `source` with `.` (a single dot) and the relative path after it with a full, absolute path, then it should work according to the answer linked above.

Comment: Great! Feel free to self-answer your question if you like, I'm on the run and currently don't have the time to write a full answer.

Comment: Please @no_name post the answer to your question if Lukas does't do it and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Lukas Graf:

Replace source with . (a single dot) and the relative path after it with a full, absolute path